# Authorization name does not meet the identifier naming rules (DB2 SQL)

Tags: sql, db2

I am new in using DB2 and SQL, recently I installed the IBM DB2 Express C on my PC. I tried to create a new database, or connect to the sample database.

I typed `create database abc` , the system respond `operation failed because the specified authorization name does not meet the identifier naming rules. Authorization name: "'". SQLSTATE=42602.`

The problem is that I have no idea how to change the authorization name.

Anyone have any idea on how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"Authorization name" is in this case your login ID, which, [according to the manual](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001029.html?pos=2), can only contain single-byte characters. I suspect that yours may not comply.

Comment: How to change your OS user ID? You probably can't on most operating systems, you'll need to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

As told in the above answers it is because your login user name is not as per the  identifier naming rules (DB2 SQL).

You can change it by going to computer right click manage.
Go to Local Users and Groups.
Go to Users and change the name.
This should solve the issue.